# timeago equivalent for Android

Tags: android, date, localization, timeago

Is there an equivalent in Android for [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)?

It is really important that the dates are not just 'pretty printed' but also updated as time goes by.

Some projects/resources with similar functionality (I will update this list if I find more):

- [android-timeago](https://github.com/bancek/android-timeago)
- [android DateUtils](http://warodridev.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-time-ago.html)
- [android-ago (Highly recommended)](https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago)

Comment: its unlikely that a library would provide the auto-refresh you are looking for, best to implement that yourself.

Comment: @j_mcnally is `new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period)` a good approach to make the auto-refresh?

Comment: it depends how often it needs to refresh, etc. Is it something you could do in an activity?

Comment: @j_mcnally `android-ago` (the third library linked above) already does the auto-refresh. It refreshes the TextView only as often as required. For example, if the time difference is more than a minute ago, then it will refresh only every minute. **Disclosure: I am the author of this library**

Comment: @curioustechizen i get date and time from server api which i want to set it in your lib so how i cant set it kindly guide me about this

Answer (score 2):

Here is your TimeAgo method.

One can get updated time-ago by calling this method just by passing milliseconds.
You can change it by sending date format or date String as per your requirement.

```
public class TimeAgo {
    public final static String monthAgo =  " month ago";
    public final static String weekAgo =  " week ago";
    public final static String daysAgo =  " days ago";
    public final static String hoursAgo = " hour ago";
    public final static String minAgo =  " minute ago";
    public final static String secAgo = " seconds ago";
    static int second = 1000; // milliseconds
    static int minute = 60;
    static int hour = minute * 60;
    static int day = hour * 24;
    static int week = day * 7;
    static int month = day * 30;
    static int year = month * 12;

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static String DateDifference(long fromDate) {
        long diff = 0;
            long ms2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // get difference in milli seconds
            diff = ms2 - fromDate;

            int diffInSec = Math.abs((int) (diff / (second)));
            String difference = "";
            if(diffInSec < minute)
            {
                difference = diffInSec+secAgo;
            }
            else if((diffInSec / hour) < 1)
            {
                difference = (diffInSec/minute)+minAgo;
            }
            else if((diffInSec/ day) < 1)
            {
                difference = (diffInSec/hour)+hoursAgo;
            }
            else if((diffInSec/ week) < 1)
            {
                difference = (diffInSec/day)+daysAgo;
            }
            else if((diffInSec/month)<1)
            {
                difference = (diffInSec / week)+weekAgo;
            }
            else if((diffInSec/year)<1)
            {
                difference = (diffInSec / month)+monthAgo;
            }
            else
            {
                // return date
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTimeInMillis(fromDate);

                SimpleDateFormat format_before = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                difference = format_before.format(c.getTime());
            }


            Log.e("time difference is: ","" + difference);
            return difference;
    }
}
```

Comment: can it auto refresh or not?

Comment: That's the purpose of this method. @Adnanhaider 
It will compare your passing data to current date time and provide the result.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings @fernandohur,

I've published such a library that answers your requirement.

*TimeAgo* is a simple java library that converts a date/time as a relative 'time ago' or 'within time' text format.

It uses pure java dates/time handling, so, it have no dependences such as joda-time api, thus, you can use it in android applications.

link: [Timeago on Android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4707)

Usage (Java):

```
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
String text = TimeAgo.using(timeInMillis);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14383807)

Comment: Yes @HåkenLid ... in short, the shared library can answer that, #TimeAgo is a simple java library for displaying dates as relative time ago language.